# FInd the volume of the solid generated by revolving the first quadrant bounded area...

Tags: calculus

The region is bounded by the graphs of the equations xy=2,y=1, and y=2  about the line y=-1.

I understand that one must use shells to solve.

I don't understand why one must integrate with respect to y. I thought one would integrate with respect to x because x gives the vertical distance between the line y=3 and xy=2.

Comment: One need not use shells. "Washers" work fine. With wahers we need to  evaluate two (sinple) integrals instead of one, because of the geometry.

Comment: how do you use the washer method on this problem? I'm having trouble with putting xy=2 into one of the radiuses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Shells, we integrate with respect to $y$ because the shells are generated by horizontal strips. running from $y$ to $y+dy$.  The strips have height $x$, which is $\frac{2}{y}$.
The radius is $y-(-1)$. "Add up" (integrate) from $y=1$ to $y=2$.

Alternately, we could use washers, so slicing perpendicular to the $x$-axis. A picture will show that from $x=0$ to $x=1$, we have a cylinder of radius $3$,  with a cylindrical hole of radius $2$. Then from $x=1$ to $x=2$ we have outer radius $\frac{2}{x}+1$ and inner radius $2$.

We leave you with these geometric descriptions. Writing down the integrals should follow fairly easily once the geometry is under control.

Comment: if integrating with respect to y means generating horizontal strips, then how can you conclude that the radius is y- (-1)? the radius is composed of vertical strips, not horizontal strips

Comment: for the washer method, from x = 0 to x = 1, the outer radius is 3 and the inner radius is 2?

Comment: Only for a while, $x=0$to $x=1$. Then the shape changes, nd the outer radius is "curvy".

Comment: for the first comment i'm assuming that one can conclude that integrating with respect to x means generating vertical strips, even for expressing what the radius is for the shell method

Comment: In the integration with respect to $x$, we are taking cross-sections, which are circles with circular holes.